# Regular expressions not matching first instance of last character in pattern

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, webserver

Sorry for the confusing title but I'm not sure how better to explain it.

I am building a simple web server for a school project that has to parse a custom scripting language. I have a line that looks like this:

```
<p>Here's the date: <% pr date() %></p><p>Here's the date again: <% pr date() %></p>
```

I'm using the following regular expression to try and pull out the <% ... %> stuff...

```
<% *(.*) *%>
```

The problem is it is matching from the first open tag to the last closing tag, rather than from the first open tag to the first closing tag. So the resulting match is this:

```
<% pr date() %></p><p>Here's the date again: <% pr date() %>
```

...instead of:

```
<% pr date() %>
```

I thought I could solve it by using something like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<% *([^(<%)]*) *%>
```

...but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is it is matching from the first open tag to the last closing tag

You need a non-greedy match which stops upon the first time a match is recognized:

```
.*  --> greedy ("maximum munch")
.*? --> non-greedy ("minimal munch")
```

The non-greedy quantifier can of course be applied to most other patterns.

However, I would advice against using regexes. The meta-pattern `OPEN-TOKEN CONTENT CLOSE-TOKEN` is simple enough for a hand written parser/scanner. It will then also be easier for you to recognize when your tags are within comments (and possibly other cases were you don't want a match):

```
<!-- <% xyz %> -->
```

Code like above might not be encouraged by you, but you have to consider that.

---

*Footnote:* Each time you `(write a parser|fire a regular expression)`, you are in prison with one leg already.

Comment: Thank you, can you point me in the direction of a resource that might explain the alternative to regexes with more detail? I'm not sure where I would start if I were to write a hand written parser/scanner.

Comment: It might make sense to insert a value dynamically in a comment as well. T4 templates for instance do not take account the grammar of the enclosing text.

Comment: It's a very simple scripting language that really just mimics an "echo" in PHP along with a couple of functions like date() for the current date. I just don't really know what you mean by a handwritten parser, the only solution that came to my mind was to use regular expressions to find what I'm looking for in the string so I'm just wondering how else I could find them at all. Do you mean to just manually iterate through the content one character at a time myself?

Comment: @AdamWathan: `Do you mean to just manually iterate through the content one character at a time myself?` -> Indeed. You could then add state to the parser as needed, for special cases (if needed at all). Don't forget to check that the lookahead character is not beyond the limits.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.*` which is greedy quantifier

Use `.*?` instead of `.*` which is a lazy quantifier

i.e Use the regex `<%(.*?)%>`

---

So,`<%(.*)%>` would match till the **last** `%>` it finds

`<%(.*?)%>` would match till the **first** `%>` it finds